# How can I download the source code of Artifactory NPM modules?

Tags: npm, artifactory

I need the source code of the NPM modules inside the artifactory installation @jfrog folder `artifactory-oss-7.7.3/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/@jfrog`. Checking the package.json files I see the following

```
,"_resolved": "https://entplus.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/@jfrog/nodejs-commons/-/@jfrog/nodejs-commons-2.0.2.tgz"
```

However, when I try to follow the link I get a Forbidden error. I also see references to a git repository:

```
git.jfrog.info/~odedb/jfrog-artifactory-nodejs-client.git
```

However, I get a timeout error for accessing. Any clue on how to download these files?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Artifactory OSS source code can be downloaded from https://jfrog.com/open-source/.
The direct download link: [https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/[RELEASE]/jfrog-artifactory-oss-[RELEASE]-linux.tar.gz](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/%5BRELEASE%5D/jfrog-artifactory-oss-%5BRELEASE%5D-linux.tar.gz)
[RELEASE] is replaced automatically to latest, if you need specific version, pls replace with version number.